# How can I preserve and later resume a thread's execution state?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an unusual scenario where I need to be able to suspend and later resume the execution state of a thread, potentially resuming it on a different thread.

There are two functions that do exactly what I want, `Thread.GetCompressedStack` and `Thread.SetCompressedStack`, but both are deprecated and there is no alternative provided. The MSDN references `CompressedStack.Capture`, but it doesn't allow the captured stack to be resumed.

Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do that in managed code, and even in native it would be hard. Note that "CompressedStack" has almost nothing to do with actual stack - it is basically list of CAS permissions/denies for current call... Consider providing info on your actual goal as there may be less insane ways to achieve it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I have a library that retrieves resources. External code saturates a thread pool with tasks that call into my library. Retrieving a resource can take a very long time (potentially minutes), and thousands of tasks could request the same resource, blocking other tasks whose required resources are already cached. I want to suspend the waiting tasks to free up the thread pool's threads; I control the thread pool and the retrieving, but not the tasks being run on the thread pool.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee - The text in your comment should be in your question. Right now your question is quite clearly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/144156). You'd be better off solving your underlying issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity: 'What is the best way to X?' is subjective and not an appropriate question for StackOverflow, however.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee - You've got a fairly specific requirement. I think it would make for a good question.

Comment: Properly written async `Task`s should not be blocking any threads... Not very clear what your restrictions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompressedStack` is not the CLR execution stack. Does not do what you want.

Basically, you can't do this as asked literally.

Thanks to `await`, though, you can kind of do this if you are OK with making the entire call chain return `Task`s. You can pause any task using a [`PauseToken`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods.aspx). Your code would then look like:

```
async Task MyCode(PauseToken pt) {
 while (true) {
  await DoSomething();
  await pt.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
 }
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can suspend and resume TASKS, but not changing its Thread.

But you can chain operations in different TASKS, I mean, you may divide your routine in some pieces and process them together, waiting their answers to start a final TASK - and all operations I describe can be suspended and/or chained to start a task only if the result is already available.

You can also monitor resources to suspend and continue your tasks, if the problem is related to this.

See complete description of possibilities in:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx